# How to fix git clone error on Jenkins agent machine?

Tags: jenkins, master-slave, jenkins-agent

I'm getting git clone error on agent machine

```
ERROR: Error cloning remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not init /root/workspace/edjos
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$5.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:997)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$2.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:752)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:161)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.RemoteGitImpl$CommandInvocationHandler$GitCommandMasterToSlaveCallable.call(RemoteGitImpl.java:154)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
```

I configured agent git path also but the same error

Comment: The error is seems to be with the remote url. Is your SCM path correct? Are you passing repo as an unresolved variable ? `git remote -v`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if git is really there:
Execute `whereis git` in your jenkinsfile

and than check your
Jenkin> Global Tool Configuration
again.

Comment: everything configured properly but same issue. so created new slave machine. now its working fine.